# What is an $n$-gluon amplitude?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

What exactly is meant when we speak of an n-gluon amplitude? For example, in case of $n = 6$: Does the $6$-gluon amplitude refer to all possible diagrams that involve six gluons (which means e.g. diagrams with two incoming and four outgoing gluons but also diagrams with three incoming and three outgoing gluons, etc.)?

I came across this terminology while trying to understanding the section about on-shell recursion (Section 27.6, Page 555) in Schwartz, *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model*.

Comment: It would help if you cited a source for this terminology.

Comment: Sorry I thought the terminology was general. Added the source in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 gluon means 6 total gluons in the amplitude. This could be $2\to4$ or $3\to3$ or any of the other possible combinations.

This distinction is not made since you can move incoming particles to outgoing ones (or vice versa) by changing the momentum of the particle $p \to -p$. For instance, the $3 \to 3$ scattering amplitude can be obtained from $2 \to 4$ scattering amplitude by taking $p_3 \to - p_3$ everywhere in the $2\to4$ amplitude.

The fact that different scattering amplitudes are related in this way is a property known as **crossing symmetry**. This is a conjectured property of amplitudes with lots of evidence and many partial proofs, but it is not proven in complete generality. We do know that it is true perturbatively, but a non-perturbative proof is missing.

---

There was some confusion about crossing symmetry in the comments so let me make it clear.

Suppose the $3 \to 3$ amplitude is $A_{3\to3}(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6)$ and suppose the $2 \to 4$ amplitude is $A_{2\to4} ( p_1 , p_2 , p_3 , p_4 , p_5 , p_6)$. Then, crossing symmetry implies
$$
A_{3\to3}(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6) = A_{2\to4} ( p_1 , p_2 , - p_3 , p_4 , p_5 , p_6)
$$
Also,
\begin{align}
A_{1 \to 5}(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6) &= A_{3\to3}(p_1,-p_2,-p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6) \\
&= A_{2\to4} ( p_1 , - p_2 , p_3 , p_4 , p_5 , p_6)
\end{align}
We also have
$$
A_{4 \to 2}(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6) = A_{3\to3}(p_1,p_2,p_3,-p_4,p_5,p_6) 
$$
and so on and so forth.

Basically crossing symmetry says that if you know ANY 6 point amplitude, you know ALL the 6 point amplitudes.

Comment: So that means that the physical amplitude $M(1,2 \rightarrow 3,4,5)$ is mathematical equal to $M(1,2,-3 \rightarrow 4,5)$? But shouldn´t be there some sort of distinction which particles are incoming and which ones are outgoing? For example $M(1,2,3 \rightarrow 4,5)$ and $M(1,2 \rightarrow 3,4,5)$ are not related via crossing symmetry, because $M(1,2 \rightarrow -3,4,5)$ is not the same as $M(1,2 \rightarrow 3,4,5)$.

Comment: @maxxam - What do you mean by $M(1,2 \to -3,4,5)$ and how exactly is that different from $M(1,2 \to 3,4,5)$? I feel there is some confusion in your comment. I have modified my answer to add more details.

Comment: Maybe we just disregard, what I wrote in my first comment ^^. Your clarification definitly helped me!